# Generating JVM bytecode for a unary not expression

Tags: java, compiler-construction, jvm, javac, bytecode

Let's say you're writing a Java (or subset-of-Java) compiler and you want to generate bytecode for a unary not expression, `!E`. You're past type checking so you know `E` has type `boolean`, i.e. it will push a `1` or a `0` on to the operand stack.

One way to do it is something like (in Jasmin syntax):

```
E
ifeq truelabel
iconst_0
goto stoplabel
truelabel:
iconst_1
stoplabel:
```

i.e. if there's a 0 on the stack push 1, else push 0. Another way to do it, taking advantage of the fact that a `boolean` is just an `int` with value `1` or `0`, is to say `!E = (E + 1) % 2` and generate

```
E
iconst_1
iadd
iconst_2
irem
```

Is there an advantage to using one over the other? Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't count on the following definition to hold true on the bytecode level.

```
true == 1
```

On the binary level (and its almost language independent), a boolean is usually defined as

```
false == 0
true != 0
```

The javac compiler apparently also follows this definition (all checks in javac bytecode I have seen just always checks agains ZERO, never against ONE).

And it makes sense to use this definition for boolean instead only treating 1 as true, C also defines it this way (true is just != 0, not simply 1) and in assembly code this convention is also commonly used. So java also using this definition makes it possible to take/pass java booleans to other code without any special conversions.

I suspect your first code example (with the ifeq) is the only way to correctly implement the not-operator for booleans. The ^1-method (xor with 1) will fail if the boolean value is not strcitly represented as 0/1. Any other int value would cause the expression to work incorrectly.

Comment: The JVM spec says: "The Java virtual machine encodes boolean array components using 1 to represent true and 0 to represent false. Where Java programming language boolean values are mapped by compilers to values of Java virtual machine type int, the compilers must use the same encoding." http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.3.4

Comment: @isbadawi That describes how the JVM encodes *arrays* of booleans and how Java compilers must encode booleans as ints *when and if they do that at all.* It isn't immediately relevant to the question.

Comment: @EJP It seems kind of ambiguous to me. The first sentence is about boolean arrays, but the second is about boolean values. I'm probably wrong though.

Comment: @isdabawi I find the wording in the JVM spec very confusing. First, it makes a comment about how the Oracle VM *does* implement boolean[] as byte[] (but I regard this comment *not part of the spec*). Then, the last two sentences talk about what a *java compiler* is supposed to do when implementing boolean[] as int[] - again this doesn't really say how the VM must implement boolean. In fact I see nothing that says the VM has to implement it in a certain way, it only gives constraints how it will interpret certain constructs that a compiler may generate for boolean[].

Comment: I doesn’t look confusing to me. The sentence “*The Java Virtual Machine encodes boolean array components using 1 to represent true and 0 to represent false*” clearly addresses the JVM. So it implies that even if a particular implementation uses byte arrays under the hood, this *must not* show through, i.e. reading from a boolean array must produce either zero or one, nothing else. Interestingly, the recent version I experimented with, does *not* implement a “nonzero means true” rule, but rather truncates all but the lowest bit when using an int value other than zero or one as a boolean.

Answer (score 5):

I once tried to write a Java decompiler, so I used to know what code javac generated. As I recall, javac 1.0.x used `!E = E ? false : true` while javac 1.1 used `!E = E ^ 1` (bitwise XOR).

Comment: I hadn't thought of `^ 1`; that's definitely better than the second one. Do you know the rationale behind switching from the former to the latter, or why `^ 1` wasn't used in the first place?

Comment: Actually I just tried with `javac 1.6.0_26` and it generated the first one (except `ifne` instead of `ifeq`), so I guess they switched back. I guess I'm still wondering about the benefits of one vs. the other.

Comment: This is just a wild guess but perhaps they moved these sorts of micro-optimisations to the JIT, which is probably where they belong.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard that modulus operations can be very slow. I don't have a source for it, but that makes sense given how much simpler it is to add than to divide. Then again, it may be the case that jumping the program counter around too much can be in issue, in which case the if/else approach wouldn't work too well.

With that said, I would suspect Neil's `E ^ 1` is the fastest, but that's just a hunch. All you have to do is pass the number through one logic circuit, and you're done! Just one operation rather than a handful.

Comment: ^1 is definetly *much* less computationally intensive than div/rem and conditional branches are also somewhat costly (since they can cause branch misprediction penalties with most current CPU architectures). The bigger question is if its valid to assume the int serving to implement the boolean is strictly  constricted to the values 0/1.

Comment: I believe in Java, it is. In any case, you could just do `(E & 1) ^ 1` if you didn't know.

Comment: (&1) ^ 1 converts 0x2 to 0x1 (for example). true == !true isn't really what one expects. I don't know of any simple expression to get the logical OR of all 32 bits of an int to collapse into a single bit. Either booleans are *strictly* constrainted, or the ^-method can't be used.